# Wordpress: Remove links from list of posts gathered by a category

Tags: php, regex, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have list of links to posts that belong to a category. The list is present on the posts. The code that generate the list is following:

```
<?php 
$sel_works = new WP_Query('category_name=Selected_Works&showposts=-1'); while($sel_works->have_posts()) : $sel_works->the_post(); 
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ;?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><span class="CatSep"> / </span></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I wonder if there is a way to remove a link in the list that is pointing to the post that we are already on. I have difficulties defining conditions, help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$current_id = get_the_ID();
$query_settings = array(
    'category_name'=>'Selected_Works',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
    'post__not_in'=>array($current_id)
);
$sel_works = new WP_Query($query_settings);
while($sel_works->have_posts()) : $sel_works->the_post(); 
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ;?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><span class="CatSep"> / </span></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```